# Why stack overflow exception is thrown on different call numbers?

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

Consider this code:

```
    private static int i = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        ++i;
        DoSomething();
    }
```

Each time I run it, I get `StackOverflowException` on a different value of `i` variable. For example *16023*, *16200*, *16071*.

What's the reason behind this? Is it a bug in C# compiler?

Comment: AFAIK, the CLR makes no guarantees about the maximum depth of the stack.

Comment: What is the maximum depth of the stack?

Comment: That's my point - the CLR doesn't provide any guarantees. And so: *Is it a bug in C# compiler?* **No**. But 16k is really, really pushing it.

Comment: I have got same exception

Comment: Execute the same code in Release mode and the number comes as 128800... This is about 80 times higher

Comment: @ZeNo You mean 8 times right?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance yup, my bad :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of unbounded recursion is implementation defined. Implementation defined means it can do *anything*. The program can terminate at any time (or never terminate), throw an unhandled exception, or whatever. For example compiling as MSIL and running on a 64-bit OS, the program never terminates for me. This is because the jitter is permitted to turn the recursion into a loop, which the 64-bit jitter does. Asking why it terminates at a particular value serves no practical purpose because the runtime is permitted to do *anything*.

Comment: Nice explanation. So, runtime has full authority to either stop and throw an exception, or continue recurring.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd really describe tail-call as a loop, but I guess it conveys the same

Answer (score 1):

Your stacksize isn't big enough.

You can increase your default stacksize by starting a new thread and define the new stacksize in the constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    private static int i = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread T = new Thread(DoSomething, 100000000);
        T.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();



    }

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        ++i;
        DoSomething();
    }

 }
}
```

Stackoverflow now happens at 1.5 million recursive calls.

Comment: There is no stack size big enough for an infinite dive (excluding tail-call)